# Onety-one or Elebenty-Leben

Tags: numbers

Why is 11 (eleven) not pronounced onety-one or elebenty-leben, and why is it considered the ghetto way of saying eleven?

Comment: Why would it be pronounced "elebenty-leben"?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why do eleven and twelve get unique words and not end in "-teen"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/why-do-eleven-and-twelve-get-unique-words-and-not-end-in-teen) and [Why eleven is not called onety one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115873/why-eleven-is-not-called-onety-one).

Answer (score 2):

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eleven):

> c.1200, elleovene, from Old English endleofan, literally "one left" (over ten), from Proto-Germanic *ainlif- (cf. Old Saxon elleban, Old Frisian andlova, Dutch elf, Old High German einlif, German elf, Old Norse ellifu, Gothic ainlif), a compound of *ain "one" (see one) + PIE *leikw- "leave, remain" (cf. Greek leipein "to leave behind;" see relinquish)

The name for the number has roots in other languages, whose words have actual meaning behind them.